# Save contents of a hash to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, nokogiri

Slowly getting there with what i am trying to achieve. I am grabbing data via screen grab and want to save the data to my model, i have two columns, home_team and away_team. So far i grab the data.

```
FIXTURE_URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures"

def get_fixtures # Get me all Home and away Teams
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
home_team = doc.css(".team-home.teams").map {|h| h.text.strip }
away_team = doc.css(".team-away.teams").map {|a| a.text.strip }
#team_clean = Hash[:home_team => home_team, :away_team => away_team]
#team_clean = Hash[:team_clean => [Hash[:home_team => home_team, :away_team => away_team]]]
end
```

I have hashed out the two ways of getting the data into a hash, one is a hash and the other is a hash within a hash, I am not sure which one i need (if any?)

So if i want to save the data received from my home_team i run a rake task to do this

```
def update_fixtures #rake task method
Fixture.destroy_all
get_fixtures.each {|home| Fixture.create(:home_team => home )}
end
```

What i want to achieve is to be able to save home_team and away_team at the same time. Do i need to access the data within the hash, if so how? Bit lost here, but this is the first time i am attempting this

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML or the link to the FIXTURE_URL?

Comment: apologies, link to URL updated in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
FIXTURE_URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures"

def get_fixtures # Get me all Home and away Teams
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
  matches = doc.css('tr.preview')
  matches.each do |match|
    home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
    away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
    Fixture.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team)
  end
end
```

This will loop through the matches and create a new `Fixture` with away and home teams for each match.

**Edit:**

Added `.text.strip`

**Edit 2:**

This should get you the dates too,

```
FIXTURE_URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures"

def get_fixtures # Get me all Home and away Teams
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
  days = doc.css('#fixtures-data h2').each do |h2_tag|
    date = Date.parse(h2_tag.text.strip)
    matches = h2_tag.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]').css('tr.preview')
    matches.each do |match|
      home_team = match.css('.team-home').text.strip
      away_team = match.css('.team-away').text.strip
      Fixture.create!(home_team: home_team, away_team: away_team, date: date)
    end
  end
end
```

It's a bit more complicated than the previous code because it has to use some XPath to call the next HTML element after the `h2` tag containing the date.

It loops through all the `h2` html tags in the `div#fixtures-data` HTML then grabs the `table` tag directly below/after each `h2`.

Comment: Amazing that works, now the understanding part... so tr.preview holds the match info, then we loop through each preview grabbing the home team and away team info, then create simply allows us to create a record in the model, if you could explain anything i have miseed that would be great

Comment: Sounds right to me :) The `tr.preview` grabs all match/fixture table rows and essentially creates an array containing the HTML from inside each `tr.preview` row. The loop grabs each HTML row snippet from the array and queries it further looking for `.team-home` and `.team-away`.

Comment: so i was going about it the wrong way, thank you for clearing that up for me, quick question then, if i wanted to grab fixtures including date could i follow similar pattern making matches = doc.css".fixtures-table full-table-medium") then i could loop through contents within this ?

Comment: not sure how to grab the dates and assign to the relevant fixture